# Execute the Start command with a variable in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, db2, sqlplus

Is there a way to execute the **start** command with a **variable** as name. Actually, I need to provide a path that changes, but the filename is still the same, thus I decided to put a value in a user variable via Define or Accept

However, I receive error when I issue:

```
define name /home/andres/myfile.sql
start &name

-- Same error
start &name.

-- With an env variable, the same problem appears. (defining name in the shell)
start $name
start %name%
```

How can I execute a script with a dynamic name directly from SQLPlus? I know that I can do that from shell, but that will be platform dependent.

Finally, I am using CLPPlus, and that should have the same behavior as SQLPlus.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work for me on Unix. Next time please provide the error.
Your code errors : SP2-0136: DEFINE requires an equal sign (=)

Define needs an = sign.

dual.sql

```
select * from dual;
```

start.sql

```
start &1

define filename=/home/oracle/dual.sql

start &filename
```

Run script

```
SQL> @start dual

D
-
X


D
-
X
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have forgotten the equals sign.

Comment: I am using CLPPlus and I got this error: DB250205E Attempt to read file '&.sql' failed. It is a DB2 error in the CLPPlus console.